# How do I inherit from Pathname in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, inheritance, pathname

I have a `RemoteFile` that inherits from Pathname

```
class RemoteFile < Pathname
end
```

I create a remote file, and get its parent

```
    irb> RemoteFile.new('.')
     => #<RemoteFile:.> 
    irb> RemoteFile.new('.').parent
     => #<Pathname:..>
```

Is there any way to get Pathname to return RemoteFiles besides monkey-patching a dozen methods in Pathname?  Wouldn't it work better if Pathname returned objects of type `self.class.new`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could consider delegating to an actual `Pathname` object. Have a look at [this article](http://www.simonecarletti.com/blog/2009/12/inside-ruby-on-rails-delegate/). This way you wouldn't have to monkey patch anything, and because of delegation, you could modify things in a safer, more controllable way.

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me so far:

```
class Winpath < Pathname
   def to_s
      super.tr("/", "\\")
   end

   def +(other)
      self.class.new super(other)
   end
end
```

Seems like +(other) is the only function you need to overload.

Answer (score 0):

In fact you can just reopen the Pathname class instead of inheriting it.